# Microsoft 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 reboot

Tags: iis

I'm aware that this might sound like a silly question but I never used a microsoft server. I'm working on a HP G6 ML350 server. I need to get dd image of the disks. If I shutdown this server now, clone disks(by mounting read only) on another linux machine and put them back on, will this server boot as normal? Is there a security mechanism on this device which might lock this device or block service?

This device is critical for my university.

PS: I don't know the admin password of the device.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any full disk encryption (i.e. Bitlocker) in place?

Comment: Why don't you use the built in Windows Server Backup to backup this server?

Comment: as i mentioned in the post , i dont have the login credentials. Also i'm not aware of the encryption of the system.

Comment: You might be able to shut the server down, boot it off a Hiren's boot disk, and use that to reset the admin password.  All bets are off if there's encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you don't modify the origin server data, cloning won't affect it at all.

The most common security mechanism could be Bitlocker which encrypts disk contents and if your server has it, you will need [Dislocker](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/) and the recovery files in a USB key or the recovery password.

Having everything set, you will clone the disk, but usually HP servers contain additional partitions for recovery and boot. Just make sure you copy the entire content of the disk.

If destination hardware is different than a HP G6 ML350, you will definitively need to login into the cloned version of your server, because you will need to install device drivers.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I don't want to setup a new device. I only want to clone images for backup purposes. Do I still need device drivers? Or does live booting the server with a linux usb is a better idea than unplugging the disks?

Comment: Use a linux usb live distro to use server's RAID controller.configuration (if any). You will only need device drivers if you restore the image to a server with different hardware components than the original.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether RAID is being used. If so, you'll need to duplicate the disk while the system is running as it will be easiest. If you want to minimize changes, disconnect the system from the network during this process.

Same applies if full disk encryption (i.e. bitlocker) is being used though this isn't commonly used in servers.

Comment: hi, as i mentioned on post, i dont have the login credentials for this server.

Comment: If the device is "critical" to the University, someone will have access.